# Compute the volume of the domain in $R^3$ given by the inequalities

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, cylindrical-coordinates

:

$x^2+y^2+z^2\leq100$.

$x^2+y^2\leq99$

$x\geq0$

$y\geq0$

$z\geq0$

I tried to use cylindrical coordinates but could not identify my limits for $z$.

Comment: There is no "integral of inequalities". There are integrals of functions over (surface of) the region bounded by the inequalities. What is your function?

Comment: I edited the title, I hope it helps 

Comment: Upper limit of $z$ is simply $\sqrt{100 - r^2}$ where $r^2 = x^2 + y^2 \leq 99$

Comment: @MathLover: you could move your last comment into your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the bounds for the $z$ variable, use the first inequality to get
$$
f(x,y):=-\sqrt{100-(x^2+y^2)}\le z\le \sqrt{100-(x^2+y^2)}=:g(x,y)
$$

By symmetries, the volume is given by
$$
V = \frac18\iint_{x^2+y^2\le 99}\left(\int_{f(x,y)}^{g(x,y)}1\;dz\right)dxdy
$$

Now proceed with cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: I sadly did not really understand the symmetries and the  bounds of $z$

Comment: @MathLover: well, do you know that the first inequality is a ball of radius 10 in the space?

Comment: Yes. And I think I am with you now. I did not see the minus sign for $f(x,y)$. But still do not know the symmetries! Could you show a plot or something?

Comment: I have upvoted :)

Comment: @MathLover: Thanks. Feel free to ask if you have other questions.

Comment: Yes, see my edit above pls.

Comment: I will be back later. @MathLover

Comment: @MathLover: Think about the 2D analogue. Do you know how to find the "area" of the region bounded by: $x^2+y^2\le 10$; $x^2\le 99$; $x\ge 0$; $y\ge 0$? Fort this 2D problem, you don't need any integrals; just draw a picture.

Comment: @MathLover: for "symmetries", I mean the region in your problem is $1/8$ of that without the last three inequalities.